# Akka, Camel and HTTP polling

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka

I see Apache Camel has a polling consumer (http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) and I was wondering if there is any way to use this from Akka to poll a HTTP REST API?

Other similar questions, [Consumer Poll Rate with Akka, SQS, and Camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771021/consumer-poll-rate-with-akka-sqs-and-camel) and [Akka for REST polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654631/akka-for-rest-polling) seem to implement the polling logic themselves, I would prefer to just use what camel provides if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options (the example codes are in Java):

1) Use the "[timer](https://camel.apache.org/timer.html)" (or quartz for more advanced purposes) Camel components. Then you need a very simple **Timer Actor** which is calling in every period a new HTTProducer Actor:

```
    public class TimerConsumer extends UntypedConsumerActor{

    //Generates an event every 60 seconds:
    @Override
    public String getEndpointUri() {
        return "timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=15000";
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object m) throws Exception {
        if (m instanceof CamelMessage){
            System.out.println("New Event (every 15sec)");
            Akka.system().actorOf(Props.create(HTTProducer.class)).tell("http://google.com", getSelf());
        }
    }
}
```

2) Use an [**Akka Scheduler**](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/scheduler.html)

```
//Somewhere in the beginning of your application (Global.java for Play Framework 2)
ActorRef httpActor = Akka.system().actorOf(Props.create(HTTProducer.class));
//A message every 15s to the httpActor
Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(Duration.Zero(),
Duration.create(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS), httpActor, "http://google.com",
Akka.system().dispatcher(), null);
```

And the common **HTTProducer** Actor used for both options 1) and 2) is as follows (simplified for testing purposes):

```
public class HTTProducer extends UntypedProducerActor {

    @Override
    public String getEndpointUri() {
        return "http://empty.com";
    }

    @Override
    public Object onTransformOutgoingMessage(Object m) {
        if (m instanceof String){
            Map<String,Object> headers=new HashMap<>();
            headers.put(Exchange.HTTP_URI, (String)m);
            headers.put(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "GET");
            return super.onTransformOutgoingMessage(new CamelMessage(null,headers));
        }
        return super.onTransformOutgoingMessage(m);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteResponse(Object m) {
        if (m instanceof CamelMessage){
            CamelMessage message=(CamelMessage) m;
            System.out.println("Response: " + message.getBodyAs(String.class, getCamelContext()));
            System.out.println("Code: " + message.headers().get(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).get());
        }
    }
```

So I recommend the second approach, since you just need to create an Actor and an Scheduler

Comment: Thanks, Ill give the second approach a go.